# Cannot Update On Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, postman

I get problem.

This is my controller

```
public function finish(Request $request)
{
    $result = $request->input('data');
    //$data = json_decode($result, true);
    return $this->InvoiceBayar($result);
}

public function InvoiceBayar($result)
{
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    $transaction = $data['transaction_status'];
    $type = $data['payment_type'];
    $order_id = $data['order_id'];
    $fraud = $data['fraud_status'];
      Fee::where('invoice',$order_id)
      ->update([
          'status' => 'Paid',
      ]);
      echo "Transaction order_id: " . $order_id ." successfully transfered using " . $type;
}
```

This is my Route

```
Route::POST('/notification', 'SnapController@finish');
```

When Payment gateway, send a parameter to me, I cannot update DB.
But when I use POSTMAN. I success update DB

Comment: You get any error?

Comment: hi @SaurabhDhariwal,, I think, I don't get any error..

Could you please fix this?

Comment: What's the response you get ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$request->all()` as it will contain all payment gateway data.

```
public function finish(Request $request)
{
   $result = $request->all();
   return $this->InvoiceBayar($result);
}
```

Comment: This is true, looking at the response that OP posted, there is no 'data' passed from the payment gateway, hence providing no data to update.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can do this

```
$update = Fee::where('invoice',$order_id)->first();
$update->status = 'Paid';
$update->save();
```

Comment: Do you have a column 'status' in your database?

Comment: hi Harun,, yes I do, fill not paid

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function InvoiceBayar($result)
{
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    $transaction = $data->transaction_status;
    $type = $data->payment_type;
    $order_id = $data->order_id;
    $fraud = $data->fraud_status;
      Fee::where('invoice',$order_id)
      ->update([
          'status' => 'Paid',
      ]);
      echo "Transaction order_id: " . $order_id ." successfully transfered using " . $type;
}
```